# Change variables of the subscript into the script in the loop

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script that takes a file and performs an *operation* with this file. During the operation the *out_file* is produced. When it's done, I start the other script (`script_2`) into my script to perform another operation on the *out_file*. But the problem that I have is to pass parameters to the `script_2`, which are different for each initial file:

```
#/bin/bash
for i in $(ls folder); do 
.\*operation*.sh folder/$i           # this step produces the *out_file.$i*
.\script_2 *out_file.$i* parameter_1 parameter_2
done
```

Thus, the `parameter_1` and `parameter_2` should be different for each out_file. So, is it possible to pass different parameters every time inside the loop and don't launch the `script_2` separately, every time for each file?

Comment: how different would be `parameter_1` and `parameter_2`? And how do you want to set them? You want to write them manually? or are they dependent on the file's name? or is it contained in some other file?

Comment: also, don't call other scripts using `.\ ` from bash, but using `./` the backslash operator is likely to get interpreted as an escape for the following character.

Comment: As per @zmo you need to clarify where p_1 and p_2 are.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, the parameters I usually write manually, its just numbers: ./script_2 1765 9037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any more information it's hard to know what your purpose is:

```
$ ls
script1.sh  script2.sh  script3.sh  testfiles

ls ./testfiles/
file1.txt file2.txt

$ cat script1.sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls ./testfiles/); do
        ./script2.sh $i
        ./script3.sh ./testfiles/out_file.$i parameter_1 parameter_2
done

$ cat script2.sh
#!/bin/bash

touch ./testfiles/out_$1.txt

exit

$ cat script3.sh
#!/bin/bash

    echo "dollar1: $1
    dollar2 $2
    dollar3 $3 "

$ ./script1.sh
dollar1: ./testfiles/out_file.file1.txt
dollar2 parameter_1
dollar3 parameter_2
dollar1: ./testfiles/out_file.file2.txt
dollar2 parameter_1
dollar3 parameter_2

$ ls ./testfiles/
file1.txt  file2.txt  out_file1.txt.txt  out_file2.txt.txt
```

As you can see it loops through all files in the folder, creates the out file and then passes this into script 3.

I wouldn't advise you run the script again in the current format (it'll loop through the out files then) but you get the idea.